# download password protected file from owncloud with python

Tags: python, python-3.x, httprequest, owncloud

How can I download a password protected file inside `python`?

The file is shared via `Owncloud` and the access is protected with a password by `Owncloud`.

I know it works with `curl` by using:

```
curl -u "FileId:FilePw" -H 'X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest' "https://exampledomain.com/public.php/webdav/" >output_file
```

The field file id `FileId` is extracted from the shared link.

Comment: there are web pages which can convert `curl` command to many different languages and modules - even to `Python` and `requests`. ie. [Curl Converter](https://curlconverter.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are web pages which can convert `curl` command to many different languages and modules - even to `Python` and `requests` - ie. [Curl Converter](https://curlconverter.com/)

```py
import requests

headers = {
    'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
}

response = requests.get('https://exampledomain.com/public.php/webdav/', 
                        headers=headers, 
                        auth=('FileId', 'FilePw'))
```

And this needs only to save response in binary mode

```
with open('filename.ext', 'wb') as fh:
   fh.write( response.content )
```

Answer (score 1):

***You can nest the command into a system call with os module***

```
system_object = os.system('your command')
```

**or fork a new process and use the subprocess run**

```
myProcess = subprocess.run()
```

***requests module allows you to use http commands***

```
import requests
headers = {}
response = requests.method(params)
```

the important part is that you assign an object variable to the instance method so that you can work with the file object